# What is SqlExpressionVisitor

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am new to ServiceStack & OrmLite, during my work, I frequently come across `SqlExpressionVisitor`

And my question is:

What is it basically? and what are the benefits of using it? And can I get the raw string query out of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have Enumartion, on which you can do, Linq queries: Where, OrderBy, Skip, Take. this goes through the enumeration and returns you a resulting Enumerable.

With ORM Lite (and Entity framework) you can also do this. But instead of using IEnumerable they use IQuerably. This interface gives you the same usages as these LINQ queries, but behind the scene these are not compiled to DLL code. Instead they are kept as `Expressions`.

The `SqlExpressionVisitor` reads this expression and tries to turn it into a SQL Query, which can be executed and returning a `IEnumerable<T>` of this `IQuerable<T>`, which is a list of results from the query.

You can also this way build your own IQueryable LINQ provider: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx (for a third party api or other databases).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, do you know how to get the raw query string out of SqlExpressionVisitor in Ormlite?

Comment: @BakriBitar It's OrmLite's LINQ Expression Builder, in most cases you can get the generated SQL with `q.ToSelectStatement()` but you would also need to use any DB Params added with `q.Params`.